Как в AngelScript лучше сделать bindigs к union type
Для саморазвития изучаю AngelScript и пишу bindings к SFML.
Как и во многих библиотеках в качестве типа Event в SFML используется структура со вложенным union.
Как я понимаю, в самом AngelScript поддержки union нет.
Вопрос в том, как лучше "эмулировать" типы, подобные sf::Event/SDL_Event?
UPD: Понятно, что типы, используемые в union нужно будет регистрировать. Интересно, как реализовать доступ к полям внутри.

Сделать по одному типу для каждого вида event. т.е. один для KeyEvent, другой для TextEvent и т.д.

https://gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=154272&page=11&m=3084937#m164 - интересный способ...

@user7860670 это понятно, что типы, используемые в union нужно будет регистрировать. Интересно, как реализовать доступ к полям внутри.

Я бы не делал никаких привязок к событиям, а обработал бы их в отдельных функциях, это упростило бы задачу, например как в с#, на каждое событие свой обработчик, без всякого месива из объединений
